# How do I sort a Realm relationship query?

Tags: swift, realm

I have two models in my Realm database to capture the idea that parents have children:

```
class Parent: Object {
  dynamic var firstName: String
  dynamic var lastName: String
  var children: [Children] {
    return linkingObjects(Children.self, forProperty: "parent")
  }
}

class Children: Object {
  dynamic var firstName: String
  dynamic var lastName: String
  dynamic var parent: Parent?
}
```

The following query works to get a list of children for a given parent:

```
dataArray = ParentObj.children
```

But what I would like to achieve is a sorted list of children.

```
dataArray = ParentObj.children.sorted("firstName")
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parent.children` is of type `[Children]` (or `Array<Children>`), not of type `Results<Children>`. Swift's Array type doesn't have a `sorted` overload function which takes a `String` parameter, but `Results` [does](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift7Results6sortedu__Rdq_CS_6Objectqd__Ss12SequenceTypezqqqd__S2_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementVS_14SortDescriptor_FGS0_q__Fqd__GS0_q__), which is probably the source of this confusion.

So to sort a Swift Array, you can use the `sort()` function that takes a closure:

```
dataArray = ParentObj.children.sort { $0.firstName < $1.firstName }
```